# Get Json object or loop

Tags: jquery, json, socket.io

I have the following json:

```
{"sockets":{"16":true},"length":1}
```

I need to get the values of the sockets, already tried with loop and several other ways more can not. Can someone help me?

Already I tried this:

```
$.each(json, function(idx, obj) {
    alert(obj);
});
```

Comment: Is the json object in string format, and what does the alert give you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var obj= {"sockets":{"16":true},"length":1}

$.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(key) + ": " + JSON.stringify(value) );
});
```

codepen-http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/ZOBgvK

Comment: To get only value of sockets ,use alert(stringify(obj));

Comment: Updated codepen with same variable names and created another for the same code - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/wWoVmB  Hope this works

Comment: You know how I would do to just get `{"16":true}` ?

Comment: Yes!! The value you need is actually the only 16

Comment: $.each( json, function( index, obj ) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(json.sockets)) ;
});

Comment: It will alert two times , as we are alerting it in the .each loop , so it will display 2 times due to length of object

Comment: Did you check in the codepen which i have provided - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/wWoVmB

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115454/discussion-between-naga-sai-a-and-rene).